# Detected package version outside of dependency constraint

Tags: dll, reference, json.net, .net-framework-version

Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.13 requires Newtonsoft.Json (= 9.0.1) but version Newtonsoft.Json 
10.0.1 was resolved.

I am in need of updating Newtonsoft.Json (>10.0.1 but am unable to as Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.13 requires Newtonsoft.Json (= 9.0.1). Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: See the answer here - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073765/version-conflict-caused-by-microsoft-net-sdk-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073765/version-conflict-caused-by-microsoft-net-sdk-functions)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE while your specific problem has long since been solved via the linked question, from time to time, the generic need to be able to work around an erroneous dependency in a package remains... This answer documents that workaround, even if it's not THE solution to the specific original problem.

---

Via [@vanillajonathan](https://github.com/vanillajonathan) in https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/385#issuecomment-1476078742, you can override (and suppress the warning) by placing an explicit `PackageReference` alongside the one triggering the conflict:

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.1">
  <NoWarn>NU1608</NoWarn>
</PackageReference>
```

See https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/issues/647 for more detail, including specific examples